# Will Leaving My Computer On All the Time Damage My Hardware?

Tags: hardware-failure

If I leave my computer on all day without turning it off/rebooting it for months, is there a possibility that it might break or something?

I hate turning it off, but I don't want it to break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the mechanical parts (fan, disk drive) might wear out sooner, but their design life is so long, a small reduction isn't going to matter. As for the electronic parts: assuming that they're adequately cooled, usage is not going to wear them out.

Still, you *are* wasting energy. If you don't care for the inconvenience of a cold boot, consider using [sleep or hibernate mode](https://superuser.com/questions/9336/what-is-the-difference-between-sleep-and-hibernate) which preserves your system state while the machine is turned off.

Comment: I don't mind wasting energy, the problem is I have an HTTP server running 24/7 on this computer